# Partition managing

Tags: boot, partition, hard-disk

I installed Kali on my 250gb hdd at installation it asked if I want to create other partitions too bad I didn't thought I will need them and now I have 1 250gb boot partition. Is it possible and with which tools to separate a piece from boot partition and create a new?

Comment: there is resize2fs and parted. Online growing is supported, shrinking is not allowed (e.g. first you have to boot from an external media and mount). The operation is more complicated than it should be, if the graphical managers do not allow you to do that, I would recommend to a novice to start over.